# can't access asp controls from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have user control with a gridview, but for some reason I can't use the asp controls from within the backend code. 
In the other user controls I can use them normally but at this particular user control it gives me error when I am trying to use a control which is used in the gridview. 
Here is the code for my gridview, please let me know if you notice something unusual:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGDG" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%" CssClass="mGrid" GridLines="None" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
    AllowPaging="True" >
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" CausesValidation="False">
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" 
            SortExpression="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
        </asp:BoundField>      
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="countrypanel" runat="server">            
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="ID"  onselectedindexchanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" />
            </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State Province" SortExpression="State_Province">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("State_Province") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("State_Province") %>'
                                 DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="StateName">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                 SelectCommand="SELECT [StateName] FROM [States]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GDG Type" SortExpression="State_Province">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GDG_Type") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGdg" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("GDG_Type") %>'
                                 DataTextField="GDG" DataValueField="GDG">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                 SelectCommand="SELECT [GDG] FROM [GDG]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Energy Type UOM" SortExpression="Energy_Type_UOM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Energy_Type_UOM") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUomEnergy" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Energy_Type_UOM") %>'
                                 DataTextField="UOM" DataValueField="UOM">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" 
                                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                 SelectCommand="SELECT UOM FROM UOM WHERE (Type = 'E')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>


                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GDG UOM" SortExpression="GDG_UOM">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GDG_UOM") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUom" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("GDG_UOM") %>'
                                 DataTextField="UOM" DataValueField="UOM">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" 
                                 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
                                 SelectCommand="SELECT UOM FROM UOM WHERE (Type = 'O')"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>     
        <asp:BoundField DataField="GDG_Coeficient_Value" 
            HeaderText="GDG Coeficient Value" SortExpression="GDG Coeficient Value" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>

<PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: By use, you mean in the browser? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I m right then. You have a User Control. Say wucMyControl.ascx, where you have a gridview control gvGDG. And u are unable to access it from wucMyControl.ascx.cs. If its the problem then use the solution below:

In your user controls designer file check the access level of the Gridview control. Might be it will get changed to private, accidently , instead of  protected. If its private , make it protected or public and check whether you are able to access it now or not.

**Update**
FYI, you can't access directly the child controls. For this you need to access in  the controls DataBound event.

Here in your case :

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(sender, e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowtype.DataRow)
     {
          var ddl = (DropdownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountry");
          // do whatever you want with ddl. Similarly you can find all html and server control inside a gridview.
     }
}
```

This will help you...

Adding event to gridview child controls

In your `GridView1_RowDataBound` method, add the handler when you create the drop down by calling `ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);`

Then, declare the `void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` method to handle your logic. The sender argument will be a reference to the drop down's that was selected. Also set AutoPostback property of the drodownlist to true.

Comment: thx for your reply, but it's still the same. It was protected, I tried with public but same thing is happening. Just fyi, I can access the gridview object in the backend code, but I can't access the controls such as dropdownlist ddlCountry.

Comment: That's how it looks like in the designer file
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gvGDG;

Comment: btw, I still can't access it.

Comment: Thanks, that got me closer to the solution, just to ask...what kind of EventArgs should I use? With GridViewEventArgs, I am getting exception 'No overload for 'Update' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'. when I am using that eventargs with 'onselectedindexchanged' event. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have some wrong with code on top line of page ASP.net designer:

Please check on CodeFile="??????" and Inherits="????????"